# change url path language using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a website with three different languages place in separate folders as below.How am I able to change the en to cn if I click on the change cn language button?

**www.example.com/en/content**

**www.example.com/cn/content**

**www.example.com/bn/content**

```
<div class="language">
   <a href="#/" id="EN" data-language="en">EN</a>
   <a href="#/" id="CN" data-language="cn">CN</a>
   <a href="#/" id="BN" data-language="bn">BN</a>
</div>
```

jquery

```
$(function changelang() {
    $(".language a").click(function(e) {
        var selectedLanguage = $(this).attr("data-language");

        var currentContent = location.pathname.substring(
            location.pathname.indexOf("/", 1) + 1,
            location.pathname.length
        );

        // console.log(selectedLanguage, " >> ", currentContent);
        window.location.href = "/" + selectedLanguage + "/" + currentContent;
    });
});
```

Comment: so what was the issue...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic problem is that you need to cancel the default link action

so add `e.preventDefault()` in your click handler.

```
$(function changelang() {
    $(".language a").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var selectedLanguage = $(this).attr("data-language");

        var currentContent = location.pathname.substring(
            location.pathname.indexOf("/", 1) + 1,
            location.pathname.length
        );

        // console.log(selectedLanguage, " >> ", currentContent);
        window.location.href = "/" + selectedLanguage + "/" + currentContent;
    });
});
```

---

And here are two alternate ways to do the same thing (*because i had misunderstood the question initially*)

Regular expression

```js
$(function changelang() {
    $(".language a").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var selectedLanguage = $(this).attr("data-language");

        window.location.href = window.location.pathname.replace(
          /\/.+\/(.+)$,
          `/${selectedLanguage}/$1`
        );

    });
});
```

---

Split, modify, rebuild

```js
$(function changelang() {
    $(".language a").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var selectedLanguage = $(this).attr("data-language");

        var currentContent = location.pathname.split('/')
        currentContent[1] = selectedLanguage;

        // console.log(selectedLanguage, " >> ", currentContent);
        window.location.href = currentContent.join('/');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much the code is working. But may I know what does it mean currentContent[1] ?

Comment: @user9030616 the `split` method of a string returns an array of the parts separated by the parameter you pass, in this case the **/**. The [1] targets the element with index 1 in that array, in this case the language, and replaces it with the new lang. Then we join the array to a string to get the new url.